# Using special character in full text search in sqlite3 (FTS4)

Tags: c, sqlite, full-text-search

I am using sqlite3 on Linux via C library(if it matters) for full text search and the database in question is a [FTS4](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2)

I store some filenames in the database and I search them as:

```
SELECT file_name FROM leTable WHERE file_name MATCH 'le name'
```

so far so good but when I want to search like

```
SELECT file_name FROM fs_index WHERE file_name MATCH 'le-name'
SELECT file_name FROM fs_index WHERE file_name MATCH 'le[name]'
```

then it fails since sqlite treat `-` as a special character and it gives me the file names including `le` but not `name`.

something similar happens when I use the characters `[` or `]` in match queries.

Using `\` didn't help so how can I escape those characters to use them in the match queries?

Comment: By default the fts tokenizer should strip out all punctuation & ignore it, does searching for 'le name' give the 3 rows?

Comment: yes indeed, but I want to narrow the results and really want to match with `le-name`